# Sequelize from routes?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

How can I access sequelize from other routes ?, all the tutorials I've seen use sequelize from app.js, but if I want to use a model from other route I'll need to initialize it everytime. how can I initialize sequelize globally and call it from other routes ?

Answer (score 1):

Kenny, try to see this example from sequelize's site: [Usage with Express.JS](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/), it's very easy to understand, and the good thing is that using this approach you can singleton all your models, it load the models when starting the application and then use the `require('models')` to grab them all and use it everywhere you like (globally).